# Don't understand aysnc. How does "the execution happen in the background"?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, dom, asynchronous, browser

I'm watching a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHSeGURldw8 about asynchronous programming with Javascript and the guy says

> "Non-blocking means the parsing will still continue and the execution
>   will happen in the background."

But isn't Javascript single-threaded? So if I have

```
<script src="somescript.js" async></script>
<script src="someotherscript.js"></script>
```

then doesn't the browser's parsing of `somescript.js` get pushed back until everything else is done?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded but that doesn't mean the entire browser has to be. There's lot of work the browser can do that won't interfere with the JS environment or the DOM.

Comment: Also, the idea that JavaScript is single-threaded is a bit antiquated. [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) now allow JavaScript in the browser to run multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the javascript code is runned in only one thread. What is executed in background is not your javascript code, but something else, usually IO, like the time to send a request to a server and get a response.

Synchronous calls would block your code execution at the request until you get a response. in a asynchronous call, the unique javascript thread still running when your browser or operation system is handling that or your data is traveling on the Internet.

Edit: I haven't saw that you was talking about "async" attribute in  html tag. About this, is just about WHEN your code will run, in moment that the tag was parsed or when page finish loading or during the loading. You still have just one thread and one javascript code per time. The paralelism with async here is about javascript code running during the page loading, not about two javascript scripts coes running in the same time.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp